# Command line args don't return correct total

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a .c program that accepts 4 command line arguments and then returns a single statement with last_name, first_name: total_payment where the total payment is the third argument multiplied by the fourth argument. I'm brand new to .c so I'm having issues with command line arguments.

```
    char* first_name = argv[1];
    char* last_name = argv[2];
    int hours_worked = argc;
    double hourly_rate = argc;
    double total_payment;
    total_payment = hours_worked * hourly_rate;
```

When I run the code it always comes out to 0.00 instead of multiplying the third and fourth arguments. Is the value in the arguments not being retained?

Comment: Why do you assign `argc` to `hours_worked` and  `hourly_rate`?

Comment: In `double total_payment; total_payment = hours_worked * total_payment;`, what are you multiplying `hours_worked` by? What does `total_payment` equal _before_ multiplication?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you think `argc` is, and what do you think you're accomplishing by setting both `hours_worked` and `hourly_rate` to it? `argc` is the number of arguments you've passed in, and `argv` is an array of these arguments. If you call

```
./main john doe 40 10.00
```

Then `argc` will be 5, and you should access the others by doing

```
char* first_name = argv[1];
char* last_name = argv[2];
int hours_worked = atoi(argv[3]);
double hourly_rate = atof(argv[4]);
```

Where `atoi` and `atof` convert a string to an integer and a float, respectively.

Comment: `stoi` and `stof` are C++, not C.

Comment: @rici My mistake. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Your math is wrong.  Change

```
 total_payment = hours_worked * total_payment;
```

to:

```
 total_payment = hours_worked * hourly_rate;
```

Also you're not initializing these values correctly, try:

```
int hours_worked = strtol(argv[2], NULL, 10);
double hourly_rate = strtof(argv[3], NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert `argv[2]` and `argv[3]` using either `atof()`. Using `atof()` for both numeric values in case one can work half an hour.

Check that the at least four arguments are passed to the program. Note `argc` will be one if no arguments are passed - for `argv[0]` which holds the program name. So `argc` will be at least 5 when the correct number of arguments are provided.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc < 5)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Insufficient arguments\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    char* first_name = argv[1];
    char* last_name = argv[2];
    int hours_worked = atof(argv[3]);
    double hourly_rate = atof(argv[4]);
    double total_payment = hours_worked * hourly_rate;

    printf("%s, %s: %.2lf\n", last_name, first_name, total_payment);
    return 0;
}
```